# Laravel / Mongodb - How to build query where count array of objects equal to total numher of competitor

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have this array **(matching_competitors)** of objects in the mongodb server:

```
"matching_competitors": [
    {
      "id_competitor": "21",
      "domain": "",
      "id_product_competitor": 224731,
      "url_product_competior": "https://www.librarie.net/p/224731/nia=1693"
    },
    {
      "id_competitor": "21",
      "domain": "",
      "id_product_competitor": 282868,
      "url_product_competior": "https://www.librarie.net/p/282868/nia=1693"
    }
  ]
```

and I have 3 competitors in **competitors** table (mysql)

Now, I need to build a query where -> size of matchig_competitors (mongodb) **should equal to** total competitor (mysql)

I can not get any idea how to build this query.

My current query:

```
$get_product = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection( 'products_' . $get_project_id->id_project )->Where( 'matching_competitors', $total_competitor )->paginate(6);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this.

```
$competitorCount = DB::table('competitors')->count();

$get_product = DB::connection('mongodb')
    ->collection('products_' . $get_project_id->id_project)
    ->whereRaw(['$expr' => ['$eq' => ['$size' => '$matching_competitors'], $competitorCount]])
    ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. let me check i t.

Comment: "message": "An object representing an expression must have exactly one field: { $eq: { $size: \"$matching_competitors\" }, 0: 0 }",